# On importance of Stockmeyer theorem

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, co-np

> Theorem: (Stockmeyer, 1974)  Any circuit that takes as input a formula
>   (in the language of WS1S) with up to 616 symbols and produces as
>   output a correct answer saying whether the formula is valid or not,
>   requires at least $10^{123}$ gates.

Suppose we have generalized theorem: Any circuit that takes as input a formula
with up to $n$ symbols and produces as output a correct answer saying whether the formula is valid or not, requires at least $10^n$ gates. Is this true that this theorem equivalent to statement that P is not equal to coNP?

Comment: I'm not sure how your title relates to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem is false. There is a circuit of size $\tilde{O}(2^n)$ that solves SAT. At any rate, the relevant conjectures you would be proving using statements of this form are the [Exponential time hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) and its variants.